# How to Make a Logo into a Button

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to make a Logo of a company so that if someone clicks on it, it will always send the user to the "home" page. I am trying to do something like

```
<label class="logo" href="Home.html">Company</label>
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any assistance would be appreciated so that when the user clicks the "Company" logo, it will send them to the home page.

```html
<div class="header2" id="myHeader">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <label class="logo" href="Home.html">Company</label>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="button2">Company</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-center">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="AboutUs.html"></span>About Us</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="ContactUs.html"></span>Contact Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="button2">Product</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-center">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="WhyUse.html"></span>Why Use</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Locations.html"></span>Locations</a>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="button2" href="#">Sign In</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-center">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></span>User Log In</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></span>Management Log In</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown language">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-center language">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#fr"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"> </span> French</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#it"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"> </span> Italian</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#jp"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-jp"> </span> Japan</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You dont need to use a button, an <a> element is perfect for this, similar to what you are already doing with your navigation:
    <a class="logo" href="Home.html">Company</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<label>` to `<a>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `<a>` tag:

```
<a class="logo" href="Home.html">Company</a>
```

You can also place the `<a>` inside a `<label>` as it is a valid in HTML.

```
<label><a class="logo" href="Home.html">Company</a></label>
```